# How I can exclude a value from a Django model?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying exclude a item from a watchlist but it don't work.

My code:

```
def watchlist(request, page_id):
    items = Watchlist.objects.all()
    item = Auction_listings.objects.get(pk=page_id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        if item_id not in items:
            add = Watchlist(auction=item)
            add.save()
        else:
            remove = Watchlist.objects.get(auction=item)
            remove.delete()
            
    return render(request, "auctions/watchlist.html", {
        "items": Watchlist.objects.all()
    })
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Your code looks fine, but the "POST" part is confusing. Do they click "delete" and that submits a form or something?

Comment: yes that submits a form. has a better way to do this without a form?

Comment: That works. An alternative method is to just generate a blank httprequest to a new page that processes your adding and deleting. But otherwise it seems like your code should work. What exactly isn't working for you? Maybe post your template and urls as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the item exists in the queryset and then go from there.

```
def watchlist(request, page_id):
    items = Watchlist.objects.all()
    item = Auction_listings.objects.get(pk=page_id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        if not items.filter(auction=item).exists():
            add = Watchlist(auction=item)
            add.save()
        else:
            remove = Watchlist.objects.get(auction=item)
            remove.delete()
            
    return render(request, "auctions/watchlist.html", {
        "items": Watchlist.objects.all()
    })
```